# State Control/Workflow in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm having an object with a few fields such as order line, reference no, state

the state is a selection of draft and confirmed

what I want is when the record's state is confirmed, the other field can't be modified/ readonly

what's the best / common way to do this in django ?
thanks

Comment: you can set that field as a Booleanfield.

Comment: @MortezaIpo Which field ? and why should I set it to boolean ?

Comment: you wanna use it in django admin or any places?

Comment: @MortezaIpo I want to use it in django admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tired it with 3 example fields.

I create a model with 3 fields:

```
class New(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True)
    body = models.TextField()
    editable = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

My forms.py code is:

```
class MyNewForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = New

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(MyNewForm,self).clean()
        title = cleaned_data.get('title')
        body = cleaned_data.get('body')
        editable = cleaned_data.get('editable')

        if self.instance.pk:
            try:
                row = New.objects.get(id=self.instance.pk)
            except New.DoesNotExist:
                raise forms.ValidationError('Record not found')

            if not row.editable and not editable:
                raise forms.ValidationError('This record is not editable')

        return cleaned_data
```

And my admin.py code is:

```
from news.models import New
from news.forms import MyNewForm
class MyNew(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyNewForm

admin.site.register(New,MyNew)
```

Hope it works fine for you.

Comment: hey, thanks for the troubles ! :D
but I've got one more thing to ask.
the code is just for validation, how to set the fields to readonly in the form ?
thanks :)

Comment: @user2469629 never do that , because if you want to edit a row all elements are readable and you should check 'editable' element and then save it and then edit that again.

Answer (score 0):

A true/false field (i.e. the `BooleanField`) can do the job. Read the docs here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#booleanfield

Comment: @mevius sorry but still don't understand,
the documentation just state that as a field that store true/false
how does it change other fields to readonly on state change ?

Comment: You can use something such as `confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=false)`. You can then use `if/else` statements to basically decide `if confirmed, fields are editable`.

Comment: @mevius where should I put the logic ?
in the custom template or in the adminmodel ?